# KeyError: "None of [Int64Index([112, 113,..121,\n .\n 58, 559],\n dtype='int64', length=448)] are in the [columns]"

Tags: python, machine-learning, cross-validation, k-fold

I used an extreme learning machine (ELM) model for predicting. I used K-fold to validate model prediction. But after executing the following code I get this message error:

```
KeyError: "None of [Int64Index([112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121,\n            ...\n            550, 551, 552, 553, 554, 555, 556, 557, 558, 559],\n           dtype='int64', length=448)] are in the [columns]"
```

How can I solve this problem? What is the wrong? The code:

```
 dataset = pd.read_excel("un.xls")
    
    X=dataset.iloc[:,:-1]
    y=dataset.iloc[:,-1:]
    
    
    #----------Scaler----------
    scaler = MinMaxScaler()
    scaler_X = MinMaxScaler()
    X=scaler.fit_transform(X)
    
    #---------------------- Divided the datset----------------------
    
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=2)
    
    # Splits dataset into k consecutive folds (without shuffling by default).
    
    kfolds = KFold(n_splits=5, random_state=16, shuffle=False)   
    for train_index, test_index in kfolds.split(X_train, y_train):
       X_train_folds, X_test_folds = X_train[train_index], X_train[test_index]
       y_train_folds, y_test_folds = y_train[train_index], y_train[test_index]
       
       # put all code in the for loop so that for every set of (X_train_folds, y_train_folds), the model is fitted.
       # call predict() for corresponding set of X_test_folds
       # put all code in the for loop so that for every set of (X_train_folds, y_train_folds), the model is fitted.
       # call predict() for corresponding set of X_test_folds
    
    #----------------------------(input size)-------------
    input_size = X_train.shape[1]
    hidden_size = 23

#---------------------------(To fix the RESULT)-------
seed =22   # can be any number, and the exact value does not matter
np.random.seed(seed)

#---------------------------(weights & biases)------------
input_weights = np.random.normal(size=[input_size,hidden_size])
biases = np.random.normal(size=[hidden_size])

#----------------------(Activation Function)----------
def relu(x):
   return np.maximum(x, 0, x)

#--------------------------(Calculations)----------
def hidden_nodes(X):
    G = np.dot(X, input_weights)
    G = G + biases
    H = relu(G)
    return H

#Output weights 
output_weights = np.dot(pinv2(hidden_nodes(X_train)), y_train)


#------------------------(Def prediction)---------
def predict(X):
    out = hidden_nodes(X)
    out = np.dot(out, output_weights)
    return out

#------------------------------------(Make_PREDICTION)--------------

prediction = predict(X_test_folds)
```

The message error:

raise KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")

KeyError: "None of [Int64Index([112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121,\n            ...\n            550, 551, 552, 553, 554, 555, 556, 557, 558, 559],\n           dtype='int64', length=448)] are in the [columns]"

Comment: Why have you used both `train_test_split()` and `KFold()`? It might be causing the problem

Comment: thank you, But after delete train_test_split() I get the the following message error    NameError: name 'X_train' is not defined      @Prakash Dahal

Comment: You can replace `X_train` with `X`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use either of `train_test_split()` or `KFold()` to split your data. **Not the Both**

As the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.KFold.html) of `KFold()` says:

You should be using only `X` inside `KFold.split()`. So use this:

```py
kfolds = KFold(n_splits=5, random_state=16, shuffle=False)   
for train_index, test_index in kfolds.split(X):
   X_train_folds, X_test_folds = X[train_index], X[test_index]
   y_train_folds, y_test_folds = y[train_index], y[test_index]
```

Also, erase all the `X_train` and `y_train` as it is not required.

```py
input_size = X.shape[1]

def relu(x):
   return np.maximum(x, 0)

output_weights = np.dot(pinv2(hidden_nodes(X_train_folds)), y_train_folds)
```

If the code is still causing error due to `KFold()`, you should consider using `train_test_split()` and replace the train, test variables of `KFold()` with variables of `train_test_split()`

For `train_test_split()`:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=2)

input_size = X_train.shape[1]

def relu(x):
   return np.maximum(x, 0)

output_weights = np.dot(pinv2(hidden_nodes(X_train)), y_train)

prediction = predict(X_test)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I replaced the train, test variables of KFold() with variables of train_test_split(). and the previous message error is disappear, but I get this message error :    ValueError: The number of folds must be of Integral type. And I want to check if I wrote my code is true or false:    output_weights = np.dot(pinv2(hidden_nodes(X)), y)    and    prediction = predict(X_test_split), but when I print the prediction, it is not printed. @Prakash Dahal

Comment: Ok, I have modified the answer and included code for `train_test_split()` can you check again?

Comment: Thank you.. I modified the code, but I still get this message error:             ValueError: The number of folds must be of Integral type. [array([[0.5       , 0.        , 0.        , ..., 0.625     , 0.                 @Prakash Dahal

Comment: have you removed Kfold() from your code? , use the bottom code that I have updated

Comment: Yes when I removed  Kfold() , the error message was disappear. Thank you. @Prakash Dahal